# In C++, how do I populate a map at compile-time, given a vector of strings?

Tags: c++, dictionary, template-meta-programming, compile-time

Given a vector of strings which is known at compile-time (and say some numbers they should map to), I wish to create such a map (f.e. `unordered_map`) at compile-time. The goal is to start up quickly and perform just look-ups at runtime. Take this example:

```
enum category {fruit, vegetable};
const std::vector<std::string> fruits = {"apple", "pear", "orange"};
const std::vector<std::string> vegetables = {"cucumber", "zucchini", "tomato"};
const std::unordered_map<std::string, category> lookup_category = // ?
```

However, `constexpr` forbids the use of non-literals. Templating is a solution, however it is a massive headache to implement and maintain.

Does C++(17?) have something in the STL which can aid me in the construction of such map at compile time?

Comment: All of the objects you want to use, utilize heap storage.  They can not be constructed at compile time.  Why not just build your lookup table when the program loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no `vector`s, `string`s, or `map`s at compile time. In fact, an object of class type with a non-trivial destructor can't be used in a `constexpr` context. So this simply can't be done.

From c++20, you can have non-trivial destructors, so this is possible in principle. As far as I know, only `vector` and `string` are available in `constexpr` contexts though, and even then, all the storage that they allocate, must be deallocated before run-time. So you can't even have a `vector` or `string` at compile time that you can also use at run-time.

From c++20, you can guarantee that the `vector` or `string`, or `map` is *initialized* at program-load time though, using the [keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constinit) `constinit`.

In case you just want to do a complex initialization of a `const map`, you can do that with an IIILE (immediately invoked initializing lambda expression) even before c++20. e.g.

```
const map<string, int> m = [] {
  map<string,int> x; // construct a map ...
  x["hi"] = 42;  // populate it
  return x;// return it
}();   // and call the expression straight away.
```